# uefi boot 18.04 mini.iso from usb stick: Stick not recognized!

Tags: boot, usb, uefi, 18.04

I prepare a stick with

```
dd if=mini.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=4M; sync
```

and try to uefi boot it.
This works well with the debian stretch mini.iso, but not with bionic beaver mini.iso (`md5sum 8388f7232b400bdc80279668847f90da`).
Also I get strange result when checking the mini.iso image or/and the stick with `testdisk`.
J.V.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Your command isn't formed properly. Have you considered specifying the mini.iso as an input file? Please see `man dd`

Comment: Did they modify the mini iso to be UEFI bootable? The older versions were not UEFI capable. Most used server and did not add much if anything with its tasksel which adds software.

Comment: Yes, the 18.04 mini.iso is uefi bootable when started from cd. (Elder Geek, I also corrected the typo in the command, thank you!)

Comment: Please refer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/738305/why-doesnt-the-minimal-image-support-uefi for further discussion and to https://www.onetransistor.eu/2015/12/install-ubuntu-minimal-cd-uefi-enabled.html for a possible qorkaround

Comment: @JohannVeterinarius, Please post a link where an uefi bootable Ubuntu mini.iso can be downloaded.